# Custom Step Definitions for Karate to test Batch

Tags: karate

Would like to be able to create custom step definitions to be able to run a batch test.  Is there a way to do this in karate?

Here is the example for the cucumber way:  https://github.com/in-the-keyhole/khs-spring-boot-batch-cucumber-demo

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason is because Karate provides a far simpler way to inject custom Java logic into a test. Here is an example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1184450203614498817

For a detailed explanation, read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/398 - which contains even more examples.